# Почему ForwardIterator2 вместо OutputIterator в std::transform?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, итераторы

Почему `std::transform` с первым параметром `ExecutionPolicy` принимает в качестве итератора для второй последовательности `ForwardIterator2`, а не `OutputIterator`, как вариант без `ExecutionPolicy`?

```cpp
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator,
         class UnaryOperation>
  constexpr OutputIterator
    transform(InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
              OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op); // тут OutputIterator

template<class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2,
         class UnaryOperation>
  ForwardIterator2
    transform(ExecutionPolicy&& exec,
              ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
              ForwardIterator2 result, UnaryOperation op); // а тут ForwardIterator2
```

Comment: Это версии `std::transform()` из разных стандартов `С++`. В стандарте `С++17` была версия с `ExecutionPolicy` и `ForwardIterator`. В стандарте `C++20` новая версия функции - без `ExecutionPolicy` и с `InputIterator/OutputIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что непонятно, как распределять output iterator'ы между разными потоками. Представьте, что там `std::ostream_iterator`. `++` для него вообще ничего не делает.